# Do 3D models have to be compiled with app using ARCore?

Tags: android, android-studio, arcore

I am trying to build an Android app using ARCore and I would need for the app to display 3D models that the user should be able to download. Is that possible somehow or is it mandatory that the obj files be compiled with the app? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Given that apps like [IKEA Place](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inter_ikea.place) exist using ARCore I expect the models to be downloadable, as I doubt every piece of furniture is prebuilt into the app.

Comment: You mean that because the size of the app would be huge otherwise?

Comment: Yup, correct thinking.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to compile 3D objects as long as you`re using format that is possible to load in runtime. For example if you're using .obj you can very easy download definition of the object and load it during runtime. For examples you can look how Poly from Google is used along with ARCore